# 2d container for polymorphic objects in c++

Tags: c++, object, boost, stl, polymorphism

I am aware of boost ptr_containers for 1D: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/ptr_container/doc/reference.html

Should I extend to 2D using a `vector<ptr_vector<BaseClass> >` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, using a `vector` of `ptr_containers` is easy and safe. I don't believe there's a special class for 2D polymorphic container anywhere.